# Need help with regular expression to parse a string of e-mail addresses in C#

Tags: c#, regex

can someone write a regex in C# for me to verify the following emails ?

aa@bb.com;cc@dfs.com;asdf@fasdf.com;sdfsdf@fsaf.com;

every email addresses are seperated with ";", and I have wrote the following regex:

```
^(([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9});)*$
```

when use this regex to match a string, it might cause a dead loop, why ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have s specific example of a "dead loop"?

Comment: I bet he sees the regex engine hang when he has a long list of email addresses and he's missing the final semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression suffers from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  I added atomic groups to your regular expression to create this:

```
^(([0-9a-zA-Z](?>(?>[-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@)(?>(?>[0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}));)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should split the email addresses and match each one against a regular expression for matching email.

1. Split the email addresses using ','
2. Match each email address against a validation expression.

Comment: but do you know why the regex above will cause problem ?

Comment: I really want to know why this will cause problem, since i just add a ":" at the end of the email regex, and then surround with ()*

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example works:

```
string s = "aa@bb.com;cc@dfs.com;asdf@fasdf.com;sdfsdf@fsaf.com;";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^(([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9});)*$");

Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch(s));
```

prints "True"

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the infinite loop on my computer with your example (I am using .NET 3.5). Here the code I used:

```
Regex rex = new Regex(@"^(([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*"+
    @"@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9});)*$");
String emails = "aa@bb.com;cc@dfs.com;asdf@fasdf.com;sdfsdf@fsaf.com;";
Boolean ismatch = rex.IsMatch(emails);
Match match = rex.Match(emails);
```

ismatch result is true and match contains data.

This other question : [How to avoid infinite loops in the .NET RegEx class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200655/how-to-avoid-infinite-loops-in-the-net-regex-class) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
 \s*[;,]\s*(?!(?<=(?:^|[;,])\s*"(?:[^"]|""|\\")*[;,]\s*)(?:[^"]|""|\\")*"\s*(?:[;,]|$))
```

This regex splits comma or semicolon separated lists of optionally quoted strings. It also handles quoted delimiters and escaped quotes. Whitespace inside quotes is preserved, outside the quotes is removed.

Hope this will meet your requirement

Thanks

~ Aamod